# SQL pivot - How to get all possible combinations between columns to be pivoted

Tags: sql, sql-server, combinations, multiple-columns, partitioning

This is my source table (pivot_dummy):

[image: Source data Table]

and I need to pivot it by Parameter_type but need all possible combinations between Parameter_val's. Something like this

[image: Desired Output]

I am using this code to get it done:

```
SELECT nct_id, [Asset],[Indication], rowid
FROM (SELECT nct_id,Parameter_val,parameter_type, rowid
      FROM (Select *,
                   Row_Number() Over (Partition By nct_id,Parameter_type ORDER BY nct_id) RowId 
            from [dbo].[pivot_dummy]
           ) a 
     ) s
Pivot (
    max(parameter_val)
        for Parameter_type in ([Asset], [Indication])
    ) as pivottable
```

but this code results in following:

[image: Current Output]

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you don't want a `pivot` at all.  Simply a `join`:

```
select pd1.nct_id, pd1.parameter_value as asset, pd2.parameter_value as indication
from pivot_dummy pd1 join
     pivot_dummy pd2
     on pd1.nct_id = pd2.nct_id and
        pd1.parameter_type = 'Asset' and
        pd2.parameter_type = 'Indication';
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, this solves my problem when there are only two columns (Asset and Indication). But actually I have 7 columns to be pivoted and also all possible combinations to be found among then, based on the NCTID, what could be the solution? Should I still think about pivoting?

Comment: @AnkurBansal . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you have asked.  If you have another question, ask it as a *new* question.